# HTML Table Download in Excel File Browser Crashing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When I try to download HTML table ( it contains 2600 rows ) as an excel file, the browser going to crash.However when it contains less records(rows) it's working fine.

For Downloading table I created a link and clicking it virtually. Here is the code.

```
var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);                   
                    var result = 'data:' + 'application/vnd.ms-' + defaults.type + ';charset=UTF-8;filename=exportData.doc;' + base64data;
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.download = defaults.fileName + '.xls';
                    link.href = result;
                    link.click();
```

Is there any other way to download with out crashing the browser?

Comment: Can you make that with PHP?

Comment: do some research first to identify whats causing it to crash

Comment: @Justinas I don't have more knowledge on PHP.

Comment: @rahultyagi may be due to the more number of rows in table

Comment: @AnilTalla that's not a convincing explanation ,do some more research on how your code works that will help you in the long run.

Comment: @rahultyagi ya i agree with you. I try by removing the encode characters